# Can you provide me with tutorials or websites that looks into generating ChangeLog when user commits new code?

Tags: git, visual-studio, changelog

I am trying to find any resource that looks into how to create/generate a changelog based on when a user commits a new change into the repository. I am using Visual Studio, so, where do I go in order to learn about this?

Side Note, does the HEAD in .git\logs contain the information about every commit that say me or someone else had done?

Comment: Beyond `git log`?

Comment: yes, I wanted to get commits author, date, and message. I managed to get the information through RestAPI but is there another way through the .git folder?

Comment: git-log(1) gives you the commit author, date, and message.

Comment: @Guildenstern using git changes will tell me about what changes have been done in a specific commit?

Comment: git-log(1) can tell you about what changes have been done in a specific commit.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for this project https://github.com/cookpete/auto-changelog

Comment: Well I am looking for something with Visual Studio and  kind of like generating a code that will create txt or any Word document extension that will have the change log information. Side Note, does the HEAD in .git\logs contain the information about every commit that say me or someone had done?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).